# grcp request payload format

Tags: node.js, http2, proto, grpc-web

I'm trying to log in into a site which requires grcp content-type using requests. I alrady have a HTTP 2 client, but I don't know how body of my post request should look like.

When I'm trying to simply copy request as a curl from chrome network tab, request body looks like this:

`%äEMAIL"PASSWORD(0`

When I'm trying to request site with same body as I copied from chrome tab, I'mm getting response with this headers:

```
Grpc-Message: grpc: received message larger than max (218767392 vs. 4194304)
Grpc-Status: 8
```

I'm sure It's becouse wrong payload format

If anybody knows how can I pass data in request plase help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send a one-off gRPC request, https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md would be helpful to know as to how to construct a message. Otherwise, using gRPC clients (https://github.com/grpc/grpc) would make more sense.